# Add Logo (Icon) and app name on the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

How can I add app logo as well as app name?
I tried, but either logo appears or app name, not both.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`setTitle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)) and [`setNavigationIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationIcon(int))?

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Title");
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.some_icon);
```

Comment: i'm a beginner and i'ts been a nightmare
thank you so much

Comment: Thanks i didn't used like that, but if i use `setNavigationIcon` it overlays `ActionBarDrawerToggle` icon when using `NavigationDrawer` like that : http://prntscr.com/c7twqu

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I'm not sure what you are trying to show. The question said nothing about a `NavigationDrawer`

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't want to show something, I just want to give information about future viewers. Sorry for bothering, have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple way :

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawerArrowDrawable);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_label_black_48dp);
}
```

You will see a screen like that :

[image]

Comment: You don't need `getSupportActionBar`, do you? You already have `toolbar`

Comment: @cricket_007 `getSupportActionBar` returns an `ActionBar` and it has these methods. `Toolbar` don't have these methods. Maybe we can cast `Toolbar` to `ActionBar` but never tried like that, let me try. @Edit : I tried to cast `Toolbar` to `ActionBar` but not allowed.